# How to add google adsense php inline html

Tags: php, html, adsense

I've successfully added G.Adsense to templates using php but I can't get it to work for inline html pages. I want a single php file for a 336x280 ad which I can draw from to insert an in-content ad to various locations on a page depending upon the page layout (therefore a template won't work).

I have a php file named adsenseseafood336.php with the following code:

```
 <?php
// AdSense 336x280 NS Seafood Pgs
?>

<!-- BEGIN 336x280 NS Seafood Pgs Ad Asynchronous -->
<script async       src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 336x280 NS Seafood Pgs -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxx"
 data-ad-slot="xxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
<!-- END 336x280 NS Seafood Pgs Ad -->
```

And on the html pages I'm trying to display the ads on I'm using:

```
 <?php include ('adsenseseafood336.php'); ?>
```

but the ads are not displaying.

I've tried a number of variations but with no success. Suggestions??

Comment: Define no success? Do you get ads but the wrong sizes? Do you get errors because the pages are not served? Have you got any messages from your access, php log files, or your client console ?

Comment: No success meaning that nothing displays, no visible change to the page.